# html <input> unable to pass value to URL unless using codeigniter's input_form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

i create form search using codeigniter's form_helper

```html
<?php echo form_open(site_url( 'lab/hasil_rawat_jalan'), array( 'method'=>'get')) ?>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="sr-only" for="value">Search</label>
  <?php echo form_input( 'value', $this->input->get('value'), 'type="text" class="form-control" id="value" placeholder="Search..."') ?>
</div>
<input class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

the problem is if i change

```
<?php echo form_input( 'value', $this->input->get('value'), 'type="text" class="form-control" id="value" placeholder="Search..."') ?>
```

into this(which mean normal input tag)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="value" placeholder="Search..." value="<?php echo $this->input->get('value');?>">
```

I can not get any value in my url, do I miss something here?

if you do not understand my question please ask. thanks^^

Comment: The advantage of using the functions of the Form helper instead of generating pure HTML is just that it's less problematic   create the form dynamically and you just pass an array instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi , what i supposed to do? i use form helper because i cant use regular html input tag.

Comment: Do you assign any values into data variable inside relevant controller method?

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali I did not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the value, please add `name` attribute.

```
<input name="value" type="text" class="form-control" id="value" placeholder="Search..." value="<?php echo $this->input->get('value');?>" >
       ^          ^
```

In code igniter, first parameter in the name of the text box.

```
<?php echo form_input( 'value', $this->input->get('value'), 'type="text" class="form-control" id="value" placeholder="Search..."') ?>
                       ^      ^
```

Comment: OMG!, what a shame to have this problem asked in stackoverflow T T . thanks dude

Comment: Its not shame bro, it happens,. Glad it helped you:)

Answer (score 0):

Here means that create and input text with `value` name with `$this->input->get('value')` this value:

```
 form_input( 'value', $this->input->get('value')...)
```

But in your case `value` become attribute, not the name of `name attribute`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="value" placeholder="Search..." value="<?php echo $this->input->get('value');?>">
```

Comment: You got it @Niranjan N Raju ;)